# vertical columns in a gridview c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want vertical columns in my `gridview` I google it but ain't get anything in  return,

rows in my `gridview` consist of only one record that is why i want to show my `gridview` `columns` `vertically`

anyone knows the easy way `(if possible)` for how to show `vertical columns` in a `gridview`?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Not possible.

Comment: i m targeting ASP.NET

Comment: well try by pivoting data row

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot will you please explain

Comment: sure if I can have some more details like dummy data!

Comment: AGE     NAME            SALARY
18     PRIYANKA         10000

AGE               18
NAME        PRIYANKA
SALARY       10000

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is the structure of your table:

```
CREATE TABLE EmpInfo(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Salary Decimal(18,8) NOT NULL
)
```

You need to `unpivot` the row to show information to convert `Row` to `Columns`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  CAST(Id as VARCHAR(200)) [Id], Name, CAST(Salary as VARCHAR(200)) [Salary]
    FROM    EmpInfo
) e
UNPIVOT
(
    Val FOR Col IN ([Id], [Name], [Salary])
) x
```

You need cast, as we need same data type for all values we are pivoting on.

Hope you can take it from here.